# View History Expansion On History

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh, command-history, history-expansion

I am having to to rewrite history expansion commands, instead of calling it from history.

For Example, I have to change 35 to 36, 37, 38.... in the following command.

```
$ print -P '\033[35mThis is the same red as in your solarized palette\033[0m'
$ !!:gs/35/36
```

Now I need to make it `!!:gs/36/37`

However, when I use the <kbd>Up</kbd> key. It does not show `$ !!:gs/35/36`. It shows `print -P '\033[35mThis is the same red as in your solarized palette\033[0m'`

What can be done here?

Comment: This is the "expansion" part of history expansion: the `!!` invocation is expanded *before* it gets added to history. I don't think there's anything you can do, but I might be wrong.

Comment: `print -P` is zsh-specific but you're tagging with both `bash` and `zsh`, and because `bash` is a more popular tag than `zsh`, the title of the page ends up being `bash - View History...`. Do you want a solution for `zsh`, `bash` or both?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I actually need a zsh solution. However, if I get a bash solution then In-Shah-Allah I will be able to make it work in zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions how you can approach what you want (referring to `bash` only):

### add it to the history

Before typing the first history expansion command line you can disable history expansion  (`set +H`) and "execute" the history expansion command (and then reenable with `set -H`). It then is part of the shell history and you can easily get back to it and modify it.

A more direct approach for getting the history expansion command line in the shell history would be `history -s`. The earlier suggestion may be easier to remember (and may be easier in case of complicated quoting), though (depending on how familiar someone is with shell options).

### readline yank

This is most useful when you do not need yanking during the whole operation.

Type the history expansion command line but do not press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Instead go to the beginning / end of the line and delete the whole line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>. This puts the whole line on the kill ring. You can restore the line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>. Even after executing the command you can get it back this way as long as you do not put anything else in the kill ring. And even if: You can go back to older kill ring entries with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

it will show that output because the terminal think that you type the whole command
example :
if i type `pacman -S vim`
i will see that `error: you cannot perform this operation unless you are root.`

so i will type `sudo !!` then before i type the password i will see a line with `sudo pacman -S vim`

[image: just a screenshot]

Comment: The OP already knows about history expansion (see `!!:gs/36/37`) but is instead asking if or how that command can be stored as a literal command in the history instead of the expanded version.